# Threading Over a List(Of Lists)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, list

I have a list object with the following structure

```
Dim urlMasterList As List(Of List(Of UrlObject) = AggregateUrls()
```

`AggregateUrls` returns lists of domain delimited urls to be consumed by a function called `UrlValidator`.  The task here is to check whether the urls in these lists are valid and if not add them to a list of broken urls.

Currently I have a nested for each loop to process this list of lists

```
For Each hostDelimitedUrlList As List(Of UrlObject) In urlMasterList                    
    For Each entry As UrlObject In hostDelimitedUrlList
        If badUrls.Exists(Function(x) x.Url = entry.Url) Then 'badUrls is the master broken list
            badUrls.Add(entry)
        Else
            Try
                If Not UrlValidator(entry.Url) Then
                    badUrls.Add(entry)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                badUrls.Add(entry)
            End Try
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I am trying to find a good method for threading over this master list.  I have tried a parallel foreach but that yielded some weird results and duplicate entries, even with locking the writing process to `badUrls`

Is this task suited for threading or should I approach it from a different angle?  Ideally I think the approach would be as follows: Have the main thread serve up chunks (5 lists from the master list) to 5 worker threads, when one finishes grab the next resource and serve it up. I cannot find any sort of example or tutorial for this type of issue.

Comment: Yes, you could thread the first loop and not the second. Especially if you actually connect to the url, if you connect a lot of thread to the same domain, the domain could see this as an attact. If you want to do your idea at the bottom, I would suggest to put everything inside a queue and each thread could pull from that queue.

Comment: Only one thread will have a group of the same domain, so no issue with multiple threads calling to the same domain, I have implemented a delay in checking to prevent ddos behavior.

Comment: If you know you have 5 threads, then each thread can have an id (0 to 4) process that index and then add 5 and process the next index (thread 0 would process index 0, 5, 10, ... thread 1 would process 1, 6, 11, ...)

Comment: Apart from the wrong result - could you notice a speedup from the threaded version? Multithreading helps for CPU-bound code, but I assume that this code is network-bound.

Comment: Some sub lists can have around 300-800 links to test, if those were running concurrently I would expect to see quite a time savings.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, since I haven't tested anything, but how about [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx)? e.g. `Dim badEntries = From list In urlMasterList.AsParallel() From entry In list.AsParallel() Where Not UrlValidator(entry.Url) Select entry`.  You will probably need to wrap `UrlValidator` to handle the exceptions.

Comment: I ended up using a parallel for each, I was simply implementing it wrong.